# Purpose of SpringBoot import, then exclude pattern?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am relatively new to Java, as a JS dev, working on a SpringBoot application I see a pattern that peaked my curiosity:

Within the `Application.java` there are several `import` classes, which are then marked `exclude` within `@SpringBootApplication`, eg

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.database.DataBaseAutoConfiguration;
...
@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = {DataBaseAutoConfiguration.class, ...}
)
```

`DataBaseAutoConfiguration` is not referenced anyplace else in the codebase, except here.

Can someone explain the purpose of this pattern? It feels odd to `import` the class then immediately `exclude` it in the configuration

Why not have something like:

`exclude = {"DataBaseAutoConfiguration", ...}` then lookup the class to ignore within Spring, avoiding the apparent "useless" import?

or:

```
// import nothing
@SpringBootApplication
```

Comment: "Meaning of the import statement in a Java file" is off topic and not helpful to this question

Comment: Please clarify. If you understand what `import` does, are you just asking what `SpringBootApplication`'s [`exclude`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html#exclude--) element does?

Comment: `exclude`'s type is `Class[]`, so it expects `Class` values, not `String` values like you suggest. There's an `excludeName` that takes a `String[]`, but you'd need to provide the fully qualified type name, so `excludeName = {"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.database.DataBaseAutoConfiguration"}`. Using the `Class` literal makes this more type safe.

Comment: I'm aware of how import works, and a bit how exclude works. The question is more how the two interact, it feels like `import thing...unimport thing` and stood out

Comment: The `import` has no effect other than letting you use the simple name of the class. You can very well have had `exclude =  {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.database.DataBaseAutoConfiguration.class}` with no `import` statement. The language feature is completely unrelated to an element of some annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** `import` is a Java language feature, `exclude` is a Spring Boot feature.

You have to `import` classes to reference them in your code. The `exclude` in this case is specific to Spring Boot and is simply instructing the spring context to not trigger any of the configuration beans inside of `DataBaseAutoConfiguration`. Technically speaking, `exclude` is a field inside of the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

The import is only required so you can reference `DataBaseAutoConfiguration` in the code. Without the import, you would get a compile error.

Comment: The reason I ask, is because the only reference to `DataBaseAutoConfiguration` is in the `import/exclude`. If `DataBaseAutoConfiguration` isnt used anywhere else, why the `import/exclude`?

Comment: If you remove the `exclude = {DataBaseAutoConfiguration.class, ...}` then yes, you don't need the import statement. But this also means your app will load all of the configuration/beans from `DataBaseAutoConfiguration`, which may not be desirable for this particular app (i.e. if you have your own custom Database configuration class that handles creation of a Datasource, etc).

Comment: Is this because somewhere down the line Spring IS going to try to call `DataBaseAutoConfiguration` even though its not referenced again in the code. In this case it is imported, in order to reference here and tell Spring to ignore it when it comes up within Spring?

Comment: Put another way: you need the import solely for the purpose of the compiler and JVM being able to find the definition of the `DataBaseAutoConfiguration` class to use in your code. You can't tell Spring Boot to exclude that class if the compiler and JVM don't even know how to load it.

Comment: Correct: presumably `DataBaseAutoConfiguration` is marked as `@Configuration` so without the exclude, Spring would scan it and load any beans and config from it.

Comment: Why not have something like `exclude = {"DataBaseAutoConfiguration", ...}` then lookup the class to ignore within Spring, avoiding the apparent "useless" import?